# Execute Script every 5 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, api

I know this is answered on multiple threads, but I still want to ask if this is the best practice for my case. I have a table called queries which has rows of API calls that needs to be done. Because I will have multiple people adding API calls need to be done to their sites using cURL, I thought to create a php script that will run every 5-10 seconds and get the last 5 rows of API calls and execute them, so I can handle everything without making the server go crazy. (With this I can also give the user an estimate time remaining for their queries to be completed). So is this the best way to achieve what I want or should I do it another way? If it is, can you briefly explain how to achieve the 5s repeat please?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I am running on CLOUDLINUX 6.7, WHM 11.52.0

Comment: If you "know this is answered on multiple threads" why ask it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this using CRON : https://askubuntu.com/questions/800/how-to-run-scripts-every-5-seconds-using-cron

You could achieve that using a cron job that kick-off a script every minute that starts 12 backgrounded processes thusly:

```
* * * * * ~/dostuff.sh
```

And the `dostuff.sh` file :

```
(sleep 5 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 10 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 15 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 20 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 25 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 30 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 35 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 40 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 45 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 50 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 55 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 60 && /path/to/task) &
```

Comment: You are amazing thank you, really got the point now. do you think this is still the best practice for my case?

Comment: There is no "best practise" in your case, it will always be tricky, but I think this is the cleanest way.